# using IF statement in mySql INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, database

How to use an if statement in mySql for example
I have this code

```
INSERT INTO covidtest ( covidTestResult ,CovidTestDate, Idnumber ) VALUES (?,?,? )
```

this will insert user's covidTest
I want to use an if statement if user has tested in 14 days

It shouldn't insert it again

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly , you don't want to inset if the testdate you are inserting is more than 14 days :

```
INSERT INTO covidtest ( covidTestResult ,CovidTestDate, Idnumber ) 
Select ? ,? ,? 
where  ? > current_date - interval 14 day
```

in where you pass date again

in query above you insert data using select statement , so you can use where to check  your condition(S) or do some sanity check
, also it works perfectly for me , see *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5e4cbea418f8a420fd0b115e3b12514b)*

in the fiddle first query meet the condition and insert the data , but second query doesn't and it doesn't insert data.

Comment: yes you understand it very well , Can you explain more

Comment: ER_PARSE_ERROR : you have an error in your sql syntax check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near '? > current_date - inetrval 14 day' at line 1

Comment: `INSERT INTO covidtest ( covidTestResult ,CovidTestDate, Idnumber ) 
Select ? ,? ,? 
from <Table Name>
where  ? > current_date - interval 14 day`

Comment: @Fabio, it could be the spelling issue which i fixed,otherwise it works fine , see fiddle link inside my answer